# format error while installing wireless adapter

Tags: wifi, raspberry-pi, raspbian

i got problem here. I try to install TL-WN725N by refering to http://blog.pi3g.com/2013/05/tp-link-tl-wn725n-nano-wifi-adapter-v2-0-raspberry-pi-driver/ web

then, when doing this command

```
sudo modprobe 8188eu
```

the error is appear like this:

```
ERROR: could not insert '8188eu': Exec format error
```

anyone please advice. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
1. uname -r //gives ur rp version number 
2. Based on the rp version number choose ur 8188eu tar file from http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=462982#p462982
3. wget https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/80256631/8188eu-201xyyzz.tar.gz
4. tar -zxvf 8188eu-201*.tar.gz
5. sudo cp rtl8188eufw.bin /lib/firmware/rtlwifi //not needed anymore if your operating system is above 3.10.33+
6. sudo install -p -m 644 8188eu.ko /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/net/wireless
7. sudo insmod /lib/modules/3.10.33+/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/8188eu.ko
8. sudo depmod -a
9. sudo reboot
```

Refer my [blog](http://goo.gl/GdOPww) as well

Comment: should run: `sudo ./install.sh`. your commands are not complete. This doesn't enable driver for wlan0 though.